# how to create android project in android studio 2.3.1 . Not giving option for android project?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am unable to create new project in latest android studio version 2.3.1. 
 [cilck here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhOVw.png)

After clicking the **create the project ** it gives following option
[Image# 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVVjg.png)

Comment: what is the error? what happens when you click on next button? I think you are starting the android studio the first time, and it is asking for the java

Comment: do you have java 1.8

Comment: thanks guys i got it. @AnkurKhandelwal what now xml part is not visible no xml files area after selecting the java project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Preferences -> Plugins and Enable Android Support.

[Android Studio Plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEhMR.png)

Looks like in Android Studio 2.3.1 it is disabled by default. 
After enabling Android Support plugin, Android Studio asked for Android SDK path and updated few libraries.
Once done I was able to Run existing and create new Android Projects.